# Contact form is not displayed correctly: CSS problem (?)

Tags: css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

i created a contact form using the WordPress-Plugin GravityForms. In the preview it looks fine and functions well, but when being implemented on the according landing page (which uses the Vanguard Theme by unisphere), the checkboxes of the form do not "fill" when somebody checks an answer: No tick etc. appears.

I have no clue how this problem could be solved, i am pretty sure that it is a problem with css.

```
/* Forms */
```

input, textarea, select { padding: 7px 9px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 21px; }
input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus { outline: none; }

I am more than thankful for your help!

Kind regards,
David

I tried to check the boxes
I expected the boxes to be "marked".
The boxes are not being filled out.

[This is how the preview looks like: i checked some boxes as an illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64NVN.png)

[CSS Code in the "Forms" section (screen css)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0UTq.png)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then read [ask] here. After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a minimal reproducible example for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just post a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: That doesn't happen here - checkboxes can be checked without problem.

Answer (score 0):

In screen.css line 1063 - input, textarea, select - remove "-webkit-apearance: none"

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I tried that. Changed the code line in the screen.css (under Design -> Theme-Editor) and saved it and updated the landing page. Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. Is there anything else i need to to, besides saving the changes and update the page?

Comment: I shared a screenshot of the css code in my initial post, if that helps. Do i maybe have to update the css code for the specific page? i just changed it in the general "theme-editor"

Comment: You sure? I tried it now with Chrome and Edge and on both i only need to remove that css property.  https://imgur.com/a/KReobj5

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. This is my first time working with css. I just went to Design -> Theme-Editor -> screen.css in WP and deleted this part of the code with backspace, then saved the changes. Is there maybe anything else i need to do? The code is not displayed as in your screenshot for me, too. The deleted part was right next to "line-hight: 21px and not below it as in your screenshot

Comment: If deleting it doesnt help you can also try to change none to checkbox. It is fine that it is next to the 21px. Maybe your side doesn't like the update.

Comment: I just cleared my cache and not it is working!! Thank you so much!